# Chunked input stream failed to receive valid chunk size:<?xmlversion="1.0"

Tags: java, web-services, soap, ant, axis

I am using Axis 1.4 version and used **org.apache.axis.tools.ant.wsdl.Wsdl2javaAntTask** to generate clientcode. However, when i tried to make a call ended up with following error,Thanks in Advance

```
  java.io.IOException: Chunked input stream failed to receive valid chunk size:<?xmlversion="1.0"
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.ChunkedInputStream.getChunked(ChunkedInputStream.java:155)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:87)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsBytes(SOAPPart.java:453)
        at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsString(SOAPPart.java:559)
        at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPPartAsString(Message.java:412)
        at org.apache.axis.handlers.LogHandler.logMessages(LogHandler.java:89)
        at org.apache.axis.handlers.LogHandler.invoke(LogHandler.java:68)
        at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:190)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
```

and the target in build.xml is,

```
<target name="generate-java">   
            <wsdl2java 
                url="${resources.dir}/2.0/popsp.wsdl" 
                debug="true" 
                printstacktraceonfailure="true" 
                output="src">
                <mapping namespace="https://www.dhl.au/popweb/gw/ws/schema/2.0/popws" 
                         package="com.soap.autogen"/>
            </wsdl2java>  
      </target>
```

Comment: Can you add your Ant target to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to address users who see later this question, I have found the root cause for this Exception. Axis 1.4 uses HTTP 1.0  to send data which are in "NoN Chunked Streams."
and if these messages hits Servers HTTP 1.1 ,where data  expected is in "chunked streams"  will possibly get this error.More about this encoding can found in [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

I have solved(without upgrading Axis), by adding a file called deploy-client.wssd which consists of the following lines.

```
<deployment
xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/"
xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java">
  <transport name="http" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.CommonsHTTPSender"/> 
</deployment>
```

This will tells the Axis to use, commonsHTTPSender which uses HTTP 1.1 by default.Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

create deploy-client.wsdd file as said Sasi.

```
<deployment
xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/"
xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java">
<transport name="http" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.CommonsHTTPSender"/> 
</deployment>
```

add dependency to your pom file

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```

and then address the file in your code

```
System.setProperty("axis.ClientConfigFile", path-of-your-file);
```